# Exception in SubscribeToStreamingNotifications

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm getting mailbox exception for quite some time now, not even once was the streaming subscription made successfully since the last month.

Exception:
**Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: 67f43d90-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7a296a993f38 because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information. The mailbox may have been moved recently.**

My code to create subscription:

```cs
 private void CreateSubscription()
        {
            var events = new List<EventType>
            {
                EventType.NewMail,
                EventType.Created,
                EventType.Deleted,
                EventType.Modified,
                EventType.Moved,
                EventType.Copied,
                EventType.FreeBusyChanged
            };

            if (_subscription != null)
            {
                ((StreamingSubscription)_subscription).Unsubscribe();
                _connection.RemoveSubscription((StreamingSubscription)_subscription);
            }

            _subscription = _exchange.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(subscriptionFolders, events.ToArray());
            _connection.AddSubscription((StreamingSubscription)_subscription);

            if (stopwatch.IsRunning)
            {
                stopwatch.Restart();
                var e = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                logger.LogFatal($"Stopwatch restarted: {e}");
            }
            else
            {
                stopwatch.Start();
                var e = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                logger.LogFatal($"Stopwatch started: {e}");
            }
        }
```

The exception occurs at the following line:

```cs
_subscription = _exchange.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(subscriptionFolders, events.ToArray());
```

Stacktrace:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: The specified object was not found in the store., Can't connect to the mailbox of user Mailbox database guid: 67f43d90-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7a296a993f38 because the ExchangePrincipal object contains outdated information. The mailbox may have been moved recently.
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(IEnumerable`1 folderIds, EventType[] eventTypes)
   at Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService.Classes.ExchangeServiceClient.CreateSubscription() in D:\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Classes\ExchangeServiceClient.cs:line 172
   at Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService.Classes.ExchangeServiceClient.CreateSubscription(IEnumerable`1 subscriptionFolders) in D:\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Classes\ExchangeServiceClient.cs:line 131
   at Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService.Classes.SubcriptionProcess.Subscribe() in D:\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Classes\SubcriptionProcess.cs:line 154
   at Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService.EwsService.SubscriptionWorker() in D:\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega\Sourcecode\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\Mach.Omega.EwsClient.WinService\EwsService.cs:line 200
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Please note that I am able to fetch emails from the mailbox just fine, but cannot create the streaming subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Is this OnPrem or Office365 ? as a generally rule you should always use the X-AnchorMailbox header https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/06/16/best-practices-important-and-critical-headers-for-ews/, that error indicates a routing issue or stale directory information (potentially caused by replication issues in AD). If its Office365 try the MailboxGUID as the X-AnchorMailbox https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/error-improvement-for-invalid-x-anchormailbox-in-rest-api-calls/

Comment: Yes, its Office365 and I just tried adding X-AnchorMailbox header with GUID value and also with the mailbox address. I'm still getting the same error.

There was a replication activity going on in my region but according to Office365 support, it is now completed. I don't know how to solve this issue now.

Comment: just to be sure the MailboxGUID is the same as the exception says right?